# I am trying to exclude the color black when picking random colors

Tags: python

I have this random color generation code.

```
background_red = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2) 
background_green = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
background_blue = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
```

how do I make it exclude the color black?

Comment: Black has RGB vals (0,0,0) and near it (very low vals in all three will be black and dark grey). So make sure your generated color can't have low vals in all three. Also, the way your code is written, you can only get eight possible different colors, the brightest (furthest away from black) of which is only (0.25,0.25,0.25). Maybe use [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color black is 0, 0, 0 so you can simply again randomize the rgb values if you get 0, 0, 0 with using if statements, while staements and many more.

I have used while statement in here:

```
background_red = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
background_green = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
background_blue = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
while (background_red + background_green + background_blue) == 0:
    background_red = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
    background_green = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
    background_blue = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't know it was that simple.  One other question.  How can I make it so it randomly chooses between a set of integers?

Comment: `random.randint` chooses the value between two integers. for eg. `var = random.randint(0, 255` chooses a random integer between 0 and 255. BTW sorry for replying this late :)

Comment: I want the program to randomly choose between 5 integers.  So background_red would choose between 5 integers and so would background_green and blue.  Then it would create a background based on the randomly chosen integers.

Comment: For doing that, you will need to use random.choice command. Create in a list for eg `list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and then `background_red = random.choice(list)` and same with green and blue.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was really overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

When generating a random value, if you want to exclude certain possibilities, the most simple way is to loop until you generate a valid one.

```py
while(true):
  background_red = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2) 
  background_green = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
  background_blue = 0.25 * random.randrange(0, 2)
  if any((background_red, background_green, background_blue)):
    # if all values are 0 (black) don't break
    break
```

If you wanted to exclude a large amount of possible values, it would be better to have a smarter approach, but for these cases you'll find this is more than enough.

Comment: You could do this a little more succinctly via `if any((background_red, background_green, background_blue)):`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm editing it

Comment: Comment might be clearer stated: `# if any component is not 0 break.`

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
N = 30
background_red = max((255 * random.random()), N)
background_green = max((255 * random.random()), N)
background_blue = max((255 * random.random()), N)
```

where N is a cut off for how dim the colour can be 0 is full black but 1, 1, 1 is extreamly close so you may want to play around with N, this version will pick random values between 0 and 255 the maximum value for RGB though im not sure exactly what parameters you are using to get te colour from your RGB valuesso this may not work for you

Comment: The problem with this is that there are more colors excluded that are not black. For example, (0,0,1) would be excluded.

Comment: i've edited the answer but this will come down to the range of values allowed for RGB usually this would be 255 so 1, 1, 1, would be excluded but it so dark as to be virtually indistinguishable from black and that is intentionally removed

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you want a (basically) continuous selection of colors from color space (a cube of side length one, with one corner at the origin and three sides aligned with the three color axes), excluding some region around black at the origin. At its core, they use [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) to generate three coordinates which are somehow mapped into color space.

The following function, `v1`, generates colors uniformly in color space excluding a cube of length `k` closest to the origin (where black is). It uses the tried and true "if it's not what you want, regenerate until it is" method, as suggested by other answers (and is definitely a solid choice).

```
def v1(k = 0.5):
    while True:
        
        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()

        if any([c > k for c in [r,g,b]]):
            break

    return (r, g, b)
```

This function, on the other hand, only generates numbers once, and just maps the generated coordinates uniformly into the cube-minus-corner. Its calculationally more intensive, though there's a chance, depending on what the stream from `random` is, that it will go faster than `v1` (though that's unlikely, and is more unlikely the smaller `k` is.

```
def v2(k):
    V = np.array([1-k**3, 1-k**2])
    P = 1 - (1-k)/V

    x1 = random.random()
    x2 = random.random()
    x3 = random.random()

    if x1 > P[0]:
        r = k + (1-k)*(x1 - P[0])/(1- P[0])
        g = x2
        b = x3
    else:
        r = k*x1/P[0]
        if x2 > P[1]:
            g = k + (1-k)*(x2 - P[1])/(1- P[1])
            b = x3
        else:
            g = k*x2/P[1]
            b = k + (1-k)*x3

    return (r,g,b)
```

`v2` *is* also what you'd want to implement a vectorized version (the math, not the logic - you'd want to make it branchless)  - so for an array of arrays of color coordinates of length `N`:

```
def v2_vectorized(k ,N):
    V = np.array([1-k**3, 1-k**2])
    P = 1 - (1-k)/V

    x1 = np.random.rand(N)
    x2 = np.random.rand(N)
    x3 = np.random.rand(N)

    r = (x1 > P[0])*(k + (1-k)*(x1 - P[0])/(1- P[0])) + (x1 <= P[0])*(k*x1/P[0])

    g = (x1 > P[0])*x2 + (x1 <= P[0])*((x2 > P[1])*(k + (1-k)*(x2 - P[1])/(1- P[1])) + (x2 <= P[1])*(k*x2/P[1]))

    b = (x1 > P[0])*x3 + (x1 <= P[0])*((x2 > P[1])*x3 + (x2 <= P[1])*(k + (1-k)*x3))


    return np.array([r,g,b])
```

This guy is pretty messy, but it's fast and it works for large samples (at least, much faster than doing `v1` in a loop)

Another option is to just make colors near black exceptionally unlikely: the following function, `v3`, generates colors unrestricted in color space, but the PDF of colors is a line - so the probability density of a coordinate of the color is proportional to the magnitude of that coordinate.

```
def v3():
    r = np.sqrt(random.random())
    g = np.sqrt(random.random())
    b = np.sqrt(random.random())

    return (r, g, b)
```

This one is nice, because it still allows *some* in the dark-grey region, and it's neither intensive in calculations and doesn't have the possibility of looping many times, though it has the downside of eventually getting arbitrarily *close* to black as the sample size gets larger and larger.

Other options include generating *spherical* coordinates and restricting the radius, or restricting yourself above planes normal to (1,1,1) (so, forbidding triangular pyramids as opposed to cubes). Another option is just to define a list of colors and randomly choosing from that (`matplotlib`'s built in default color sequence is accessible as `matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']`, and is a good choice for a pleasant sequence of diverse colors). Matplotlib also has nice choices in [`Colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) form, which map floats in [0,1) directly to colors, many of which do not include black.

Comment: Side note, writing the code for `v2` took a reeeaaally long time - restricting pyramids and eighth-spheres and so on would take even longer. Simpler is often better when writing code, and the whole "repeat until satisfied" method with `while` loops is probably the way to go for those, performance notwithstanding.